# How can i display form data in echo php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

How can i display form data in echo php ?

My code is:

```
<?php
    echo "<td align='center' style='vertical-align:middle;'> Bust:
    <?php
        echo $_POST["bust"];
    ?>
    <br> Waist:
    <?php
        echo $_POST["waist"];
    ?>
    <br> </td>";
?>
```

But this doesn't work, please guide me with correct steps.

Comment: Move your code to your question, there is an edit button.  Also please include the full output of your table, and post the code for your form itself

Comment: You're already inside PHP and echo, so why the added code of the same inside it?

Comment: Sorry sir @CJWurtz i am new to Stackoverflow, The error come for above code, syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\gown-gowns\web\checkout.php on line 156

Comment: you've an answer below if you haven't seen it yet, you can accept it to close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of problems with your code.

1. You're using `"` in `$_POST["bust"]` but you opened `echo` with `"` as well, causing a conflict.
2. You're using `<?php` instead an echo... which is already PHP. There's no need to do this.

It is best to isolate variable printing from your code. Use string concatenation with `.` as such:

```
echo "<td align='center' style='vertical-align:middle;'> Bust: ".$_POST["bust"]."<br> Waist: ".$_POST["waist"]."<br> </td>";
```